# How to remove an attribute when a button is clicked jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

In a rails project in my html.erb file I have a form with the submit tag:

```
    <%= submit_tag "Go!", class: 'btn btn-default', :id =>  "search_btn"  %>
```

In the same file I have a table with an attribute:

```
    <tbody id="sortable_table" data-role="activerecord_sortable" >
       <%= render @things%>
    </tbody>
```

I want a jQuery code that will remove the **data-role** attribute when the submit_tag is clicked.

Have you any ideas how can I do this?

Comment: Where is the click handler? `$('#sortable_table').removeAttr('data-role')`

Answer (score 3):

You can remove attributes using jQuery using the `removeAttr()` function.

```
$('#search_btn').click(function(){
  $('#sortable_table').removeAttr('data-role');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Laruens Swart is right,
but please take into consideration that you can do all of that with just JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("search_btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById('sortable_table').removeAttribute('data-role');
});
```

I suggest you question whether you actually need to use jQuery or not.

Comment: I appreciate you trying to use pure JS, but OP specifically said he's using jQuery. If we're going to answer all questions in the jQuery category with answers like "this can also be done with pure JS", stackoverflow will become very very messy very quickly ;-)

Answer (score -2):

You can use following js

```
$('#search_btn').click(function(){
  var attrs = $('#sortable_table').data();
  delete attrs['role'];
});
```

Comment: This does not remove the attribute from the element, but removes it from an array.